# No module named 'discord'

Tags: discord, discord.py

Пытаюсь запустить файл .py , но не может найти модуль

> File "C:/Users/****/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py", line 2, in 
> import discord

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'

`import discord`

В Python packages написано что "discord " установлен

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать библиотеку discord.py

```
python3 -m pip install -U discord.py
```

также пример импорта в .py файле

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands, channel
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
```

Comment: discord.py так же установлена

Answer (score 0):

Переустановите `discord.py`.

Введите в терминал:

```
pip uninstall discord.py
```

Затем:

```
pip install discord.py
```

Comment: все равно пишет что нету